# method to ask questions from array A and store corresponding answers in Array b (3 strings & 1 double)

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, methods, overloading

Newb/hobbiest here trying to increase my understanding of arrays and to that end i'm trying to build a little meal calculator which will store user data in an array which would hold three strings and one double (The Users First Name, The Users Last Name, the Name of the Resturant, and a DOUBLE which is the cost of the meal). I know there are far easier ways to do this then the way I'm trying to do this, but my purpose is to increase my understand of how arrays work now that i'm starting to understand loops and methods (I get lost/am scared of arrays so i'm forcing myself to work with arrays all weekend long starting tonight - long weekend and i hope it will a worthwhile weekend of learning :D )

I am currently working on a method to populate the array which would work as follows:
Call GetUserData(question asked);
GetUserData asks the user for a specific type of data (string unless last position [3] then it's a double which I'll do math on later)
GetUserData Loop calls arrQuestions[] to ask user question
GetUserData reads user answer into corresponding position in arrUserData[]
arrUserData[] is populated (at this point with four strings, i'll have to convert the four string to a double when i do math which should be feasible i hope)

So in a nutshell, i'm trying to build a method that asks a series of questions from one array and stores the answers in another array that i can then use to do all sorts of wacky things with as i try to get a better understanding of arrays and how to use them and what they are good for and what they aren't good for.

And I promise all of you I've already tried to Google an answer to this, I've read up on arrays at several places including http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx and stackOverflow, but the answers I've thus found aren't written in a way someone of my skill level understands/my understanding isn't such that I can divine the answer from what i have been able to read thus far.

The following code all sits within the 'program' class

```
public void Play()
{
   GetString("+ + +  Meal Calculator Exercise  + + +");

   String command = "";

   String[] arrQuestions = new String[3];//questions asked
   arrQuestions [0] = "First Name: ";//string back
   arrQuestions [1] = "Last Name: ";//string back
   arrQuestions [2] = "Restaurant Name: ";//string back
   arrQuestions [3] = "Cost of Meal: ";//I want a double back for this question


   String[] arrUserData = new String[3];/user answers stored
   arrUserData[0] = " ";//string 
   arrUserData[1] = " ";//string
   arrUserData[2] = " ";//string
   arrUserData[3] = " ";//figure out how to convert to double 


   do { 
      GetString("+ + +  Meal Calculator Exercise  + + +");

      GetUserData(arrQuestions[i]);//run loop, ask questions populate arrUserData array 

      GetString("Again? ");
      command = Console.ReadLine().ToLower().Trim();
      Console.Clear();
   }

   while (command == "y" || command == "yes");

   GetString("+ + +  Thank you  + + +  Have a wonderful time  + + +  Goodbye!  + + +");        
}

public String GetString(String strTxt) {
   Console.WriteLine(strTxt);return Console.ReadLine();}

public Array GetUserData(String strTxt)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < arrUserData.Length; i++)
   Console.WriteLine(arrQuestion[i]);
   return Console.ReadLine(arrUserData[i]);
}


static void Main(string[] args){
   Program myProgram = new Program(); 
    myProgram.Play();}
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a little more research, head scratching and help from the kind folks here lead me to this:

```
class Program
{
    String[] arrUserData = new String[4];// Must specify 4 in brackets for array length, not the same as an index
    // it will fill up as items are added to it starting from position 0 automatically
    // should also be at class level for multiple method access

    public void Play()
    {
        String command; // doesn't need to have an empty string value, only be declared

        String[] arrQuestions = new String[4];//questions asked 
        arrQuestions[0] = "First Name: ";
        arrQuestions[1] = "Last Name: ";
        arrQuestions[2] = "Restaurant Name: ";
        arrQuestions[3] = "Cost of Meal: ";

        do {
            GetString("+ + +  Meal Calculator Exercise  + + +"); // I removed the one in the top of the method, or else it does it twice
            // pass in array of questions to satisfy necessary array argument in GetUserData();
            GetUserData(arrQuestions);//run loop, ask questions populate arrUserData array 

            command = GetString("Again? "); // your GetString method returns whatever the console reads,
            // so it can be assigned to your command variable at the same time, or else the user has to put in y or yes twice
            Console.Clear();
        }
        while (command == "y" || command == "yes");

        GetString("+ + +  Thank you  + + +  Have a wonderful time  + + +  Goodbye!  + + +");
    }

    public String GetString(String strTxt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(strTxt); return Console.ReadLine().ToLower().Trim();
    }

    // changed it to a void to it just simply assigns the values to the class level array
    public void GetUserData(string[] thisArray)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < thisArray.Length; i++)//use the passed in array to determine loop length
        {// missing curly braces
            Console.WriteLine(thisArray[i]); // write question with corresponding index to console
            arrUserData[i] = Console.ReadLine(); // use Console.ReadLine to get input and assign it to corresponding index in userData
            if (i == 3) // check for the last index to convert to double
            {// here's the basic way, can cause a lot of errors if user input is not a double
                Convert.ToDouble(arrUserData[3]);

                // here's the way trapping all possible errors, and giving a nice message for each
                // remove the other Convert.ToDouble method and uncomment this to try giving some false values to see how it works
                /*
                try
                {
                    Convert.ToDouble(arrUserData[3]);
                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert " + arrUserData[3] + " to a Double.");
                }
                catch (OverflowException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(arrUserData[3] + " is outside the range of a Double.");
                }
                 * */
            }
        }
        SeeUserData(thisArray); // to display the user data, demonstrates nesting methods that can
        // operate off of one single variable pass in your Play method
        // you could also move it to your play method and change it to SeeUserData(arrQuestions); and it would work the same
    }

    public void SeeUserData(string[] sameArrayAgain)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here's the data for " + arrUserData[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < sameArrayAgain.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your " + sameArrayAgain[i] + " " + arrUserData[i]);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) { Program myProgram = new Program(); myProgram.Play(); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In looking at your code I'll try to recommend something that I think uses some of the existing knowledge you've shown.

I won't delve right in to code but I'll try to explain it:

I could count how many questions are in the array, (array.length) and store that. Then I would do a while loop that checks if the number of questions answered is equal to the array length. In this loop you could use console readline to put the questions one by one in to the array and increment your counter variable, then use the variable that you are incrementing to insert the answer in to the user data array.

Does that make sense? Let me know if you want any clarification or if this isn't what you were looking for.

Comment: At least conceptually it makes sense, I will attempt to see if i can work that out. Thank you for the guidance and I'll report back with results.

Comment: I seem to be stuck; I haven't been successful in trying to pass the array into the method to count it's length. Currently my 'method call reads as 'public String GetUserData(arrData){' and then method itself reads like so 'public String GetUserData(arrData){int i = 0; int step = arrData.Length; do{ Console.WriteLine(arrQuestions[i]); arrData[i] = Console.ReadLine(); i++; }while(i < step); return arrData; }' I think i'm close to feeding the arrs in and getting something back, it's still definitely no cigar.

Comment: I now call the method like this 'GetUserData(arrUserData);' and I rework the loop like so 'public String[] GetUserData(String[] arrData)
        {


            int i = 0;
            int step = arrData.Length;
            while(i <= step)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arrQuestions[i]);
                arrData[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            return arrData;
        }' Still not sure what i'm doing wrong, but it seems that the arrays arrQuestions aren't going into the method.